# Silverlight Telerik Visual Studio 2010 SP1 bug

Tags: silverlight, telerik, radchart

Silverlight application doesn't work on my machine anymore.

Screenshot:

[image: VS bug screenshot]

When I run the application the window becomes white. I copied following exception message from IE developer tools console (FF doesn't work either):

```
    Code: 4004    
Category: ManagedRuntimeError       
Message: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:  [Line: 0 Position: 0] ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   at System.Windows.Media.Animation.RepeatBehavior.Create(Object o)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.ConvertCValueForManagedWithType(Type propertyType, CValue& outVal, Int32 outDOType, Boolean releaseObjectReference, Boolean deleteBuffer, IManagedPeerBase fromObject)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.GetValue(IManagedPeerBase managedPeer, DependencyProperty property)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.Media.Animation.Timeline.get_RepeatBehavior()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodEx(IntPtr ptr, String name, CValue[] cvData)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodEx(DependencyObject obj, String name)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_ApplyTemplate(FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.LayoutStatesManager.GetElementRoot(Boolean templatesAreGenerated)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.LayoutStatesManager.Load()
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.IItemContainerGenerator.PrepareItemContainer(DependencyObject container)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.AddVisualChild(Int32 containerIndex, DependencyObject container, Boolean needPrepareContainer)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.AddContainers()
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.RecreateVisualChildren(IntPtr unmanagedObj)
```

I believe that RadChart is causing the issue.

Everything works fine on collegue's machine.

How can I fix it?

**Edit:** I think that on the client exception is thrown only when RadChart's ItemsSource is bound to data source.

Comment: Did you install the telerik controls with the msi?

Comment: No. I just downloaded latest dll's from telerik's site add referenced them. Everything was working fine yesterday...

Comment: Check you references, on your machine are they showing they're in error under references?  Also use the namespace telerik recommends in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my bad ;)

Numbers format in 'Region and Language' settings was changed (',' and '.')

After format reset RadChart works.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem, I had installed the telerik .msi and then copied the libs I needed to a lib folder in my project and referenced them.  Another person working on it got the same error, I believe.  It has to do with [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/566804/when-adding-a-reference-using-the-browse-tab-visual-studio-2010-does-not-add-the-hintpath-node-to-a-silverlight-4-csproj).  I ended up uninstalling, basically removing the telerik controls from the gac and just using the dll's download.  Maybe your colleague installed the msi?